# Find tangent line of $y=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$ at point $x=\alpha$ and it's limit position when $\alpha \rightarrow +\infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Find tangent line of $y=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$ at point $x=\alpha$ and it's limit position when $\alpha \rightarrow +\infty$.

Tangent of $y=f(x)$ at point $M(x_0,f(x_0))$ is given by equation $y−y_0=f′(x_0)(x−x_0)$

Applying this equation gives $$y_0=αe^{\frac{1}{α}},f′(x_0)=\frac{(α−1)e^{\frac{1}{α}}}{α},x_0=α$$ and tangent equation 
$$y−αe^{\frac{1}{α}}=\frac{(α−1)e^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{\alpha}(x−α)$$

How to find limit position of a tangent? Is it a limit of $y$ when $α→+∞$?

If yes, how to find the limit?

Comment: Yes... Find limit of $f(x)$ as x tends to $\infty$

Comment: @Gummy bears Do you mean $f(x)$ as the given function or tangent line?

Comment: As the given function.